# Python two conditions in for loop does not work

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement, jupyter-notebook

there is a problem in my code. I am trying to write a simple trade program, but in for loop,second if statement does not recognize variables updated in the first if statement. For example, when first if statement change total_money and total_spread, in second if statement they do not change, they are still 0. What should I do to fix this problem ? Thank you.

Outputs:

```
-1.4551915228366852e-11
1
21.771720851795823
-1.4551915228366852e-11
1
21.771720851795823


total_money = 100000
total_spread = 0
total_transactions= 0

for i in range(0,spread2_df.last_valid_index()+1):
    
    if (total_money>0):
        if(spread2_df.iloc[i,0] < spread_long_2):        
                total_spread = total_spread + ((total_money)/(-spread2_df.iloc[i,0]))
                total_money = total_money - total_spread*-spread2_df.iloc[i,0]
                total_transactions = total_transactions + 1
                print(total_money)
                print(total_transactions)
                print(total_spread)
    if (total_spread>0):
        if(spread2_df.iloc[i,0] > spread_short_2):
                total_money = total_money + total_spread*spread2_df.iloc[i,0]
                total_spread = 0
                total_transcations= total_transactions + 1
                print(total_money)
                print(total_transactions)
                print(total_spread)
            
print(total_money)
print(total_transactions)
print(total_spread)
```

Comment: Try sticking a `print` statement in the block of code that you think is updating those variables (e.g. print the updated values).  I think you'll find that it's never actually happening.

Comment: Actually I did it, It worked once and variables updated, but variables in second IF statement did not change

Comment: Put `print` statements in both blocks.  Update the code in your question to include those statements, and include the output in your question.

Comment: okay, I put prints

Comment: Your second block (`spread2_df.iloc[i,0] > spread_short_2`) is never happening.  If you put a print statement in there that says something like "block 2" you'll see that it never gets printed.  If you're not sure why that is, try printing those two values to see why the first is never bigger than the second.

Comment: How can I fix it ?

Comment: Exactly like I said: figure out what those two values are, and figure out which one of them is wrong, and then you can figure out *why* and you can fix it.  I don't know enough of the context of this code to be able to help with that.